# they are alright

Tags: phrase-meaning

At the beginning of a trial

**Judge**: Oh, so many cases to be judged today and **they are alright**.
Well, let's get started. Raise your right hand and repeat after me.
I swear to tell the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth.

**Man**: I swear to tell the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the
truth.

**Judge**: Now, where is your case? There're so many and they all look
alike. Ah, this must be it.

---

What does "**they are alright**" mean?

Comment: Did this happen in real life? If so, it appears like some idle self-talk, the same as "Now, where is your case? There're so many and they all look alike. Ah, this must be it." The judge is probably trying to self-placate that it's alright to have so many cases and be so busy. Otherwise, I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Note that many authorities consider 'alright' is either incorrect or only an informal version of 'all right'.

Comment: @SarahBowman I believe the OP is studying a series of 'English' dialogues for learners, which are unfortunately not always very natural.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I am aware of that. I wasn't sure how or if to address that in a comment. Nor where to find an authority. What puzzles me is "who" is "they" in "they are alright"? I don't know if this dialogue was verbal or written; thus I don't know if it is the spelling of the question author or a published author. Too many unknowns for me to address the spelling of "alright."

Comment: This has got to be from a TV show or a radio drama.